# prepareForSegue doesn't init new view

Tags: iphone, ios, segue

i have been looking at several turorials and all call the new view with just one line of code or more if they pass any information to the next view. At the moment i want to build a menu with segue like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {          
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; 
    if ([path row]==0) {
        MainViewController *mtvc = (MainViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    } else {
        SettingsViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];
    }       
}
```

Normaly all examples use "segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"" ". But i couldn't connect the cell of my table view inside the storyboard with more than one other view. Therefore i used the selected row to identifie which of my views should segue.

I don't know if this could occure the problem but i initialized the tableview from my splashview in this way:

```
-(void)turnNext {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    MenuTableViewController *mtvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    [self presentViewController: mtvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You don't use a UINavigationController ?

Comment: i selected the table view and embeded the navigation controller. Is there an other way when segue from the menu to the other views?

Comment: Why are you using segues and not pushViewController? I am just curious :)

Comment: i started a second time, to learn programming iOS apps for iphone and saw the different methods in a tutorial on lynda. so this time i wanted to create my project with storyboard to learn this feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)turnNext {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    MenuTableViewController *mtvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];

    [self presentViewController: mtvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
             ^^^^^^
```

change that to

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mtvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: will this change my problem for the steps after? because the switch to the table view just works with my code...
I could switch the view always programatically but i always read you shouldn't use this way often when using the storyboard in a project

Answer (score 1):

You should use segues for this purpose.

- Create 2 custom segues on your Source controller in storyboard .
- Set their identifier as 'segueToMainViewController' and 'segueToSettingsViewController'

Now, in tableView - 'didselectrowAtIndexPath' method use following.

```
//use your logic here

if(indexPath.row == 1) {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToMainViewController" sender:nil];
}
else {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToSettingsViewController" sender:nil]
}
```

You can Pass data as sender if you need to paas anything to your controllers.